# Best way to use Unix domain socket in bash script

Tags: bash, sockets

I'm working on a simple bash script daemon that uses Unix domain sockets. I have a loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    rm /var/run/mysock.sock
    command=`nc -Ul /var/run/mysock.sock`
    echo $command > /tmp/command
done
```

I'm echoing the command out to /tmp/command just for debugging purposes.

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't know, what do you want to do with the socket?

Comment: Use it to talk to the daemon from somewhere else. For example: echo "hello" | nc -U /var/run/mysock.sock

Comment: You may want to change the > to >> so it actually logs more than just the most recent command, but other than that its just as good a method as any depending on how often it gets written to.

Comment: Need a similar solution. Commenting here so I can get update if one is materialized.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like I'm late to the party. Anyway, here is my suggestion I employ successfully for one-shot messages with response:

```
INPUT=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo -m 600 "$INPUT"
OUTPUT=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo -m 600 "$OUTPUT"

(cat "$INPUT" | nc -U "$SKT_PATH" > "$OUTPUT") &
NCPID=$!

exec 4>"$INPUT"
exec 5<"$OUTPUT"

echo "$POST_LINE" >&4
read -u 5 -r RESPONSE;
echo "Response: '$RESPONSE'"
```

Here I use two FIFOs to talk to `nc (1)` and fetch it's response.

Comment: need to install netcat-openbsd to get -U option.
In ubuntu sudo apt-get install netcat-openbsd

Comment: What to do with `$NCPID`? Furthmore, where does `$SKT_PATH` come from. It has to be the path to the unix domain socket, but that is probably not clear for beginners.

Comment: Well `$SKT_PATH` is path to your socket. Regardless of where you will take it from.
You can do anything you want with `$NCPID` in case you'll need something to do with a child (nc) process.
It is not clear for beginners, but still the original poster is not a beginner if he asks about Unix domain sockets.

Comment: My first reflex was to downvote because `mktemp -u` is generally insecure, and requires care to use securely. However, at the last second I remembered that as a special case, the output of `mktemp -u` is secure when it is passed to functions which will error out if the thing has already been created, such as `mkfifo`. So then I changed downvote to upvote. But then I realized your example is not bailing out upon errors from `mkfifo`. This encourages people to write insecure scripts through teaching by example and leaving the insecurity unmentioned, so back to downvote for now.

Comment: So concretely, I would recommend following both `mkfifo` commands with `|| exit 1` in the example code, and adding a comment somewhere in the answer about how if `mkfifo` fails, this a problem in progress (at best just a bug due to two scripts doing this at the same time, at worst a malicious exploit).

Comment: Also, for maximum security we want to _first_ `mktemp -d` and _then_ do the pair of `mktemp -u` and `mkfifo` calls inside it. This adds a tiny bit of defense-in-depth: if we just create randomly named pipes, then any process with read permissions on their parent directory can see their names. (And `/tmp` tends to be world-readable.) By creating our own private securely randomly named temporary directory first, and then securely randomly named pipes inside that, we hide the pipe names to just processes running as our user, which adds one more challenge to any exploit running as another user.

Comment: To be clear, besides the above critiques about subtle race condition and security concerns, I think this is a very good answer. I want to upvote this answer, and I would if at least the point about respecting `mkfifo` errors as a name collision was addressed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single file also to use bidirectional.

```
mkfifo communicate_pipe
exec 3<> communicate_pipe

cat communicate_pipe - | python socket.py 127.0.0.1:8002  | while read line; do   
    cmd="./something.sh  '${line}' > communicate_pipe";
    eval $cmd;
  fi; 
done
```